# Skip a function call in C

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hiiiii");
    printf("welcome");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to call the second `printf` by skipping the first call to `printf`.

Comment: It is unclear what you trying to achieve. How do you want to skip the first printf? Because the first way that comes to mind is simply removing it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
//printf("hiiiii");
printf("welcome");
```

Another solution:

```
if (0) {
    printf("hiiiii");
}

printf("welcome");
```

What is it you are trying to achieve?